# Centering slider controls glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a slider with 2 arrow controls to navigate through the images.

I want to add a background to these arrows, As well as making them circular.

But this issue when I add padding to the arrows, The arrows are not centered inside the circles anymore.

Here is the CSS:

```
.item{
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img{
    display: inline !important;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon{
    padding: 30px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

jQuery to fire the slider:

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

Here is a fiddle to view and test: https://jsfiddle.net/dov7k19b . Increase the result window width to see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove/override the default width and height property of .glyphicon-chevron-left class by adding this code so you can style and center the icon inside the circle

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left{  width: 0px; height: 0px; }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` to center the icons.

```css
.item {
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img {
  display: inline !important;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon {
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```